# How to enable image upload support in CKEditor 5(Inline Editor) using require js?

Tags: html, requirejs, ckeditor5

When clicking the insertImage icon,it's showing browser to upload the image.Once upload the image,it's not insert the image.

Comment: Please refer JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vrVAP/3722/

Comment: Using Require.JS? How would you like to use Require.JS to handle image upload?

Comment: Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765197/how-to-enable-image-upload-support-in-ckeditor-5 – I explained there what are the options to enable image upload in CKEditor 5.

Comment: Can you give the sample code related to inline-editor in CKEditor5?And also see the jsfiddle added inserimage in the toolbar but it's not working.

Comment: I am not using npm to import the all the plugins.

Comment: I think that I answered all your questions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765197/how-to-enable-image-upload-support-in-ckeditor-5 and clarified it even more here https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/555#issuecomment-337564473. I'd propose to close this topic as a duplicate of that previous question.