# Image Upload in ckeditor5-react

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.6, ckeditor5

I have been seeking for any thread with the related issue, but couldn't find one, I'm trying to set an image upload for **ckeditor5-react**, picking up a file via file browser works fine but I get an **alert** "cannot upload file"

[image]

Here is my code below:

```
<CKEditor
    editor={ ClassicEditor } 
    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => console.log( { event, editor } ) }
    config={{
         ckfinder:{uploadUrl: "/uplaodImageFromEditor"}
      }}
    UploadAdapter={FileRepository}
 />
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there's no `UploadAdapter` property available in the CKEditor component.

Secondly, the image feature is based on the image upload, so you need to configure your backend, so the uploaded images can be stored somewhere. As it's explained in the [How to enable image upload support in CKEditor 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765197/how-to-enable-image-upload-support-in-ckeditor-5?noredirect=1&lq=1), so you have a few options.

If you want to use the CKFinder, then you need to install the CKFinder and provide a correct URL in the `ckfinder.uploadUrl` config. Eventually, you can use this URL as the endpoint for your own backend - see [how the backend responses should look like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49833278/2043175)  for the `ckfinder.uploadUrl` config.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have finally configured everything correctly.

Comment: What is meant by the `FileRepository` attached on the `UploadAdapter` ?

Comment: [FileRepository](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_upload_filerepository-FileRepository.html) is a plugin that you can reach via `editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' )`. The uploader can be set on this plugin using the `createUploadAdapter` method.

Comment: @sonke how did you configure it in the end?

Comment: @Sonke I am still getting alert cannot upload file even though I get success from the backend and I see my image uploaded. How to remove this alert?

Comment: Hi @DavidNelband , I'm sorry for taking so long, I can't remember how I resolved that issue but I will check and give a feedback.