# How to set responsive images with CKEditor 5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5, django-ckeditor, ckeditor.net

Using the [*Simple Upload Adapter*](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html#responsive-images-and-srcset-attribute), according to the CKEditor 5 documentation upon a successful image upload, the server should return either:

This for a single image:

```
{
    default: 'http://example.com/images/image–default-size.png'
}
```

Or this for multiple (i.e. for the srcset attribute)

```
{
    default: 'http://example.com/images/image–default-size.png',
    '160': 'http://example.com/images/image–size-160.image.png',
    '500': 'http://example.com/images/image–size-500.image.png',
    '1000': 'http://example.com/images/image–size-1000.image.png',
    '1052': 'http://example.com/images/image–default-size.png'
}
```

For starters the documentation is incorrect as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385792/how-to-do-ckeditor-5-image-uploading), so I'm not surprised this doesn't work. But does anyone know what response format CKEditor 5 is expecting for it to correctly insert/build the srcset attribute? It does take the `default` key but seems to ignore the others!

Comment: Don't you use an old version of simple upload adapter? We added support for handling responsive images there 7 months ago: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/blame/2cb7597681fcb8187a976cf15fbb962967e11271/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter.js#L179

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the `_initListeners` function of the upload adapter you will find that the Promise ***only*** resolves with the following:

```js
resolve( {
    default: response.url
} );
```

The solution - change the Promise to resolve the following:

```js
resolve( response.urls );
```

Note, in this example the response object may have either keys `url` or `urls`.

I ended up using the following as I ignore null keys in my server responses.

```js
if ( response.hasOwnProperty( 'url' ) ) {
    resolve( {
        default: response.url
    } );
} else if ( response.hasOwnProperty( 'urls' ) ) {
    resolve( response.urls );
}
```

---

As a sidenote, if you've read through the other SO post I referred to, I would also recommend removing this (see commented section):

```js
if ( !response /** || !response.uploaded */ ) {
    return reject( response && response.error && response.error.message ? response.error.message : genericError );
}
```

I'm not a fan of using arbitrary flags in response, if the upload failed then I would rather see a HTTP status code indicating it, I can't see any reason why we need to return 200 and `{ "uploaded" : false }`