# Ckeditor5 image uploading issue

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor, ckfinder, ckeditor5

I am trying to implement/ migrating (from ckeditor4) ckeditor v5.0 in a project.

The default classic editor is working fine. The issue is of image uploading.
After selecting image from popup browser is shows "Cannot upload file:".
I have already looked on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765197/how-to-enable-image-upload-support-in-ckeditor-5) question but it didn't help much.

Below is the snippet of my code:

```
<script>
        var newMyEditor;
        ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#sendedit' ),{
             ckfinder: {
                 uploadUrl: 'upload url',
             }                    
             })
            .then( editor => {
            console.log( 'Editor was initialized');
                    newMyEditor = editor;
                } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
</script>
```

Bakend - PHP v5.2
Server - Windows

Comment: Please paste your error code here

Comment: I am getting `Cannot upload file:filename.png` in alert box. no error in console

Comment: could you find solution?

Comment: Bear in mind that the ckfinder has also to be declared in the toolbar options of the ckeditor and make sure that the ckfinder.js script is loaded into your page. For more info check here > https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/ckfinder.html#demo