# Insert image to CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, electron, ckeditor5

I trying to use CKEditor5 and CKEditor-react in my electron app.
And i want to paste image in editor, but i have an error

> filerepository-no-upload-adapter: Upload adapter is not defined.

Docs says that I mast using cloud. But my app must working locally and without internet
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-filerepository-no-upload-adapter) say, in short, this:

> To handle image upload in CKEditor 5 you can use one of these:
>
> - use the built-in [Easy Image](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-cloud-services/easy-image/) adapter (cloud service),
> - use the built-in [CKFinder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/ckfinder/) adapter (can work locally if you want),
> - write your own adapter (in which case, please refer to the [`UploadAdapter` interface](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_upload_filerepository-UploadAdapter.html) documentation).

The last option gives you a complete freedom on how and where you want to send those files.

PS. You can find a bit more details in this question: [How to enable image upload support in CKEditor 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765197/how-to-enable-image-upload-support-in-ckeditor-5)