# `ckeditor` file upload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using ckeditor but the issue is that I can't upload image. all I get is alert saying "cannot upload image". the code  i am using is below.

```
   ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
    ckfinder: {
        uploadUrl: 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
    }
} )
.then( editor => {
    console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
} )
.catch( error => {
    console.error( error.stack );
} );
```

I am using ckeditor5 cdn. I can't find what is the error what is going wrong and where on server or browser. and I can't find the js code to get the message coming from server. I don't wan't to use easyimage because it use cloud and that is not free. I would rather like t use cloudinary but that would be another question.

Comment: The config you use assumes that you use the CKFinder installed. Do you have it installed? Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765197/how-to-enable-image-upload-support-in-ckeditor-5?

Comment: perfect. I solved to upload image to my server but now I want to upload to cloudinary and was thinking of writing my own adapter for this and there is none available. So thanks.. these comments are spot on.